# Customising background from both stylesheet and html

Tags: html, css, background, styling

I want to set my background styling in a css stylesheet, but want to select the background image in the html file.  Whilst the style is going to be same across the website, the image needs to be different on each page.

Example of code:

**==== CSS ====**

> body {
>       backgound-position: center;
>       background-repeat: no-repeat;
>       background-size:1200px 800px;
>       background-position-x: center;
>       background-position-y: 50px;
>   }

**==== HTML ====**
   `<html>
     <head>
       <link href="../css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
     </head>
       <body style="background:url('../img/Car.jpg');">
       </body>
</html>`

This does not seem to work.  The styling in CSS is being ignored.  Please note that the paths are correct, as all other elements work...

Also, I'm using a Bootstrap template.

Please help!

Thank you
D.

Comment: Just would be great to make sure the typo in the first line of css 'backgound' is not causing troubles.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `background:url('../img/Car.jpg');` using only background: will set EVERY background property. Simply change `background:url();` with `background-image:url();` :)